# JDBC Create a copy of a table with executeQuery() using only Java

Tags: oracle, java, jdbc

I need to print four columns from a copied database and I am required to use only JDBC. The work of printing the columns all neatly formatted is something I think I can handle. Its the creating the copy of the table and then inserting the required rows that is giving me difficulty. Is it possible to write executeQuery() strings to accomplish this? I know to INSERT the rows I need to use executeUpdate(). I would be grateful for any help or direction. Thanks.

```
    public static void main(String args[]) throws SQLException {
    // define common JDBC objects
  Connection connection = null;
  Statement create = null;
  Statement insert = null;
  ResultSet rs = null;

      // Connect to the database
      String dbUrl = 
          "jdbc:oracle:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
      String username = args[0];
      String password = args[1];
      Collection<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
      connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
          dbUrl, username, password);
      create = connection.createStatement();
      String query =
              "CREATE TABLE newTable AS " 
            + "SELECT * " 
            + "FROM oldTable; ";          
      rs = create.executeQuery(query);

      insert = connection.createStatement();          
      int rows = insert.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO newTable SELECT * FROM oldTable ");
      if (rows == 0) {
        System.out.println("No rows");
      } else {
        System.out.println(rows + " row(s)affected.");
        connection.close();
      }
    }
  }

 //and here is the combined sql statement with CREATE and INSERT:
statement = connection.createStatement();
sql = 
"CREATE TABLE newTable AS SELECT * FROM oldTable "
+ "INSERT INTO newTable "
+ "(" + " col01,col02,col03,col04, "
+ "col05,col06,col07,col08,col09, "
+ "col10,col11,col12 " + ") "
+ "VALUES " + "(" + "'data01','data02','data03','data04', "
+ "data05,data06,data07,'data08',data09,data10,data11,data12 " +")" ;
   statement.executeUpdate(sql);
```

Comment: `create table as  select ..` already inserts all rows into the new table. There is no need to run another `insert` (unless you want to double the number of rows). But you need  `executeUpdate()` for the `create table` statement. It's not a "query" (it doesn't return anything). You also need to remove the embedded `;` from your SQL statement.

Comment: thanks! so when I combine the sql statement into one string it throws the :"ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended" syntax error.

Comment: You can't run two statements with one `executeUpdate()`. But why do you want to run the `insert` at all? It is not needed.

Comment: I have to add a row for the output. so run two separate `executeUpdate()` calls?

Comment: No, to _read_ the data you need a `select` and a `executeQuery()` then process the `ResultSet`. See the JDBC tutorial for examples: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html